# How to create, download and delete file in one request

Tags: php, file, laravel-5

I need to create, zip, download and delete a file in one request in Laravel. I use the following code in my controller:

```
$pathToFile = "myFile.txt";
$content = "content";

Storage::put($pathToFile,$content);    
$file = storage_path().'/app/'.$pathToFile;
$zipFile = storage_path().'/app/'.$this->name.'.zip';
Zipper::make($zipFile)->add($file);

return response()->download($zipFile);
```

Unfortunately the zip file is not created at the time I try to download it. Therefore I got an error that the file does not exists. However after the error response the file is created and it is available. So if I run the same controller method again, the file is downloaded.

Could you please help me with this issue. I would like to be able to create the file, to download it and delete it.

Comment: Do you want to download `myFile.txt` or the zip file?

Comment: So why do you pass path to txt file to the response in `response()->download($pathToFile);`?

Comment: It is a mistake, made while describing the problem here. But it does not reflect the problem itself. I changed this.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed the issue myself. 
It is needed to call the close method of the Zipper, in order to create the file:

```
$pathToFile = "myFile.txt";
$content = "content";

Storage::put($pathToFile,$content);    
$file = storage_path().'/app/'.$pathToFile;
$zipFile = storage_path().'/app/'.$this->name.'.zip';
Zipper::make($zipFile)->add($file);
Zipper::close();

return response()->download($zipFile);
```